# WebRequest vs FileWebRequest

Tags: c#, webrequest

I am going through the example exam questions for Microsoft exam 70-483 "Programming in C#".

There is one question the answer to which I don't understand and couldn't find anything about the topic on the Internet.

The question is:

> You are implementing a method named ProcessFile that retrieves data files from web servers and FTP servers. The ProcessFile() method has the following method signature:
>   
> Public void ProcessFile(Guid dataField, string dataFileUri)
>   
> Each time the ProcessFile() method is called, it must retrieve a unique data file and then save the data file to disk.
>   
> You need to complete the implementation of the
>   ProcessFile() method. Which code segment should you use?

```
FileWebRequest request = FileWebRequest.Create(dataFileUri) as FileWebRequest;
using (FileWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as FileWebResponse)
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(dataFieldId + ".dat"))
{
    writer.Write(reader.ReadToEnd());
}
```

-or-

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(dataFileUri);
using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(dataFieldId + ".dat"))
{
    writer.Write(reader.ReadToEnd());
}
```

According to the question-making people, the latter snippet, using "WebRequest" is the correct one. But I cannot figure out why the "FileWebRequest" one isn't.

Keep in mind the questions I am doing have been wrong a lot in the past, so maybe this isn't correct, either?

Comment: A FileWebRequest would only know how to retrieve a file from an FTP server. As the requirement is to retrieve data files from webservers and FTP servers you rely on the generic WebRequest.Create to give a webrequest implementation that knows how to handle a response from either type of protocol, FTP or HTTP. It does that by looking at the url that is provided.

Comment: I must be looking at the same questions, did you take the exam and did they help?  They do seem to be incorrect a lot.

Comment: @Neil.Work they mostly help by making me research the topics and specific cases on the Internet. Yes, they are incorrect quite often and I haven't taken the exam, yet, haha.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some hours ago I also have met this question. Early I have not work with this, but by searching info in Google I concluded followings:

- the main words in question is **from web servers and FTP servers**,

  that means that **dataFileUri** may be like http://mywebserver or ftp://myftpserver
- when you try to get file from ftp server, for example:

  ```
  //from answer
  var request1 = WebRequest.Create("ftp://myftpserver");   

  //from answer
  var request2 = FileWebRequest.Create("ftp://myftpserver") as FileWebRequest;   

  var request3 = WebRequest.Create("ftp://myftpserver") as FtpWebRequest;
  ```

  request1, request3 will have request value with type SystemNet.FtpWebRequest. request2 will be **null**.

  The similar behavior will be when you try to use http://mywebserver: request2, request3 will be **null**.
- when you use WebRequest the type of the request will be automatically detected by transfer protocol

  So you don't need to think about whether file stored on web server/file server/ftp server